# Folder Treeview

Tags: c#, view, directory, treeview

I have created a Treeview showing Folder and subfolder structures and listing of files that meet  file specification (*.txt).

What I now want to do is only show the Folder structure that have a file that meets the specification.  Right now the treeview shows all folders even if they do not have files that meet the criteria.  The files can be 4 - 5 layers deep, so then I want to show that branch, but if no files exist, then I do not want to show the node structure.

Looking for coding suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

is that treeview created at runtime? 
if so, you can check if there's a file before adding a branch to the tree.